# Windows Phone Media Stream Source Seek Implementation C#

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am implementing a media streaming source in c# windows phone 8 for streaming schoutcast urls.
I can play the buffered stream from the URLs. Now I have to implement seeking over the buffered audio data. 
I tried setting forward and backward by 1 seconds from the GUI. Below is the code for rewinding

`if(BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.CanSeek)
{
    TimeSpan position = BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Position;
    BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)(position.Seconds - 1));
}`

But the player stops for long time and starts playing.

I think I have to implement the following method found in Media Stream Source implementation.

```
protected override void SeekAsync(long seekToTime)
{
 ReportSeekCompleted(seekToTime);
}
```

I would like to know how to implement forward and backward seeking using Media Streaming Source without the delay?